# Three.js - CanvasRenderer problems: flat shading?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use `CanvasRenderer` (`three.js`) as a fallback for devices not supporting `WebGL`. Is there some comparison page with explanation what is different and cannot be used with `CanvasRenderer`?

I'm experiencing two main issues:

1. flat shading, lights are completely missing (is `MeshPhongMaterial` supported?), I don't see any lighting nor shadows (are shadows supported in `CanvasRenderer`)? All I see is the diffuse texture without any lighting. In WebGL my current setup is `PointLight, DirectionalLight, softShadows, antialiasing` and `MeshPhongMaterial` (with diffuse, bump, spec and env map)

   ```
   this.materialM = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
           ambient : 0x050505,
           color : this.model.color,
           specular : 0xcccccc,
           shininess : 100,
           bumpScale : BUMP_SCALE,
           reflectivity : REFLECTIVITY,
       });
   ```
2. transparent polygon edges (I know it can be tweaked with `material.overdraw` = 0.5 yet it produces other artifacts (as it probably does only some scaling of polys along the normal?), but I can do with this one

Any help on 1. or some general overview of what is not possible in `CanvasRenderer` when comparing to `WebGLRenderer` is greatly appreciated!

three.js r68

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CanvasRenderer` has limitations.

1. `MeshPhongMaterial` is not supported in `CanvasRenderer` -- it falls back to `MeshLambertMaterial`.
2. `MeshLambertMaterial` is supported, but not when the material has a texture -- it falls back to `MeshBasicMaterial`. ( `MeshBasicMaterial` is rendered without regards to scene lights. )
3. Shadows are not supported.
4. `material.overdraw = 0.5` is helpful in hiding polygon edges when the material is opaque. It may still leave artifacts if the material is transparent.

three.js r.68

Comment: thank you for explanation! oh well, so we need to wait for Apple to enable WebGL on mobile devices (as textures&correct lighting are essential for the project)... :(